# Crop images to ratio in Modx TV

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Is there some plugin/way to crop images when they are uploaded in a Modx TV?
I got a slider with a ratio of 1:4. Now when the user uploads a image in another ratio, the image will stretch out.

I want something like Facebook does when you upload a cover image which is to high.

(PS: I want to use it later in Migx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like 'okyanet' mentioned you can use phpThumbOf to set the dimensions/ratio when MODx delivers the image.

Another way would be to use the extra '[Image+](http://alanpich.github.io/tvImagePlus/)'. You still need phpThumbOf for this, but the Editor can define the clipping manually in the Manager. And you can define the ratio of the clipping in the TV-Setting for the image.

Answer (score 1):

Use [phpThumbOf](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/phpthumbof). The 'zoom-crop' parameter will allow you to preserve the source aspect ratio and then crop it to the dimensions you require.

The image is processed when the page is parsed by MODX, rather than at the time of upload.

There are plenty of articles about how to use this extra, including this one:
http://www.belafontecode.com/image-manipulation-with-phpthumbof-in-modx-revolution/